# Enthalpy of reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, enthalpy

[image]
Please someone help me with this question
How is d possible?

Comment: It isn't. The answer options are 1, 2, 3 and 4;  there is no option for d. Also, this is a simple question to write out in legible fashion; no need for difficult-to-read sideways photograph.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ea = (delta)H + RT
i guess that ends the confusion.
Now you can adjust the last term and have all 3 cases as possible

https://lavelle.chem.ucla.edu/forum/viewtopic.php?t=13676